How to automatize extract of a data associated to another data in two columns table?
I'm actually trying to build a code than can read financials document and extract specific data.
Each pdf is build differently, but the data I'm looking for is always in a table, but this table is not in every case at the same place.
In fact, I'm searching threw 2 columns table, a data which is associated to another, for example:
[A,Cash],[B,Card],[C,Swap],[D,Stock],[E,Derivative]

My input is C and the code return me "Swap".
How can I do it while searching in the enter document and return the data as a string?
Thank you in advance, here is the code i'm actually working in :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pdfplumber
import re
import datetime
import dateparser

# Function to select a PDF file
def select_pdf_file():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Hide the main window

    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("PDF files", "*.pdf")])

    return file_path
    

def extract_and_merge_tables_with_dates(pdf_path):
    merged_data = []
    date_regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{4}|\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}|\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z].+-\d{2,4})|\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]+-\d{2,4}')
    
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        for page in pdf.pages:
            tables = page.extract_tables()
            for table in tables:
                has_dates = any(date_regex.match(str(cell)) for row in table for cell in row)
                if has_dates:
                    for row in table[1:]:
                        merged_data.append(row)
                    
    
    # Format dates to mm/dd/yyyy format using dateparser
    formatted_dates = []
    for row in merged_data:
        formatted_row = []
        for cell in row:
            if date_regex.match(str(cell)):
                parsed_date = dateparser.parse(str(cell))
                if parsed_date:
                    formatted_date = parsed_date.strftime("%-m/%d/%Y")
                    formatted_row.append(formatted_date)
                else:
                    formatted_row.append(cell)  # Keep unparsable cell as it is
        formatted_dates.append(formatted_row)

    return formatted_dates

def sort_dates(data):
    return sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%m/%d/%Y") if x else datetime.datetime.max)

# Select a PDF file
pdf_path = select_pdf_file()

# Extract and merge tables containing dates from the selected PDF
formatted_data = extract_and_merge_tables_with_dates(pdf_path)

# Sort data from oldest to newest using the first column containing dates
sorted_data = sort_dates(formatted_data)

# Remove duplicate dates in the sorted_data list
unique_dates_set = set()
unique_data = []

for row in sorted_data:
    # Convert date to string to compare duplicates
    date_string = row[0] if row else None
    if date_string not in unique_dates_set:
        unique_dates_set.add(date_string)
        unique_data.append(row)

# Print unique data without duplicates
for row in unique_data:
    print(row)

#Links on weTransfer : t-wTqa09uMLz ( i don't know how to share the pdf)

Here is the link to get the pdf file : [Product PDF]
Thank you in advance 

Welcome. Not sure if this question may be answered without input sample, i.e. here representative pdf files? Also please translate all to English.

Thank you for your advice, i translated french sentences. But do you have a tip to share my pdf properly

About sharing files: not sure myself but found this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335737/how-can-i-ask-this-question-without-resorting-to-third-party-file-sharing

To increase traffic on your post, consider adding tag [pdf-parsing] + looking for previous posts with this tag

Also if you are stuck at scrapping the desired tables, then probably consider trimming your posted code down to that and skipping the subsequent date formating. Make it a clear [mre]
